# Different (merged) partitions on GParted when installing Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-8

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside my previous installation of Windows 8. Please note that my notebook is 4/5 years old and came with Windows 7 on it.

In Windows Disk Manager, I get 4 partitions:

1. SYSTEM
2. C:
3. H: (DATA)
4. D: (which is the partition that I intend to use for Ubuntu)

However, when I attempted to install Ubuntu in GParted, it said I have different partitions -- apparently H: and D: are merged in one single partition.

I also tried the menu install option "Install alongside Windows 8", but the installer reboots and nothing happens.

Could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: post a screen shot of gparted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you tried to create a partition for Ubuntu using the Windows partitioning tool. This was a mistake, since the Windows partitioning tool converts from standard disk partitions to Microsoft's proprietary [LDM/"dynamic disk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) whenever the number of partitions exceeds four. Without more detailed information, I can't be 100% positive that this is what happened, but my hunch is that it was. Unfortunately, Microsoft provides no easy way to undo this change. I've heard that some third-party Windows tools, such as [EaseUS Partition Master,](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) can make this change, but I've never tried such tools.

Comment: Problem solved. The disk was dynamic and the EaseUS did the trick. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It would be more easy to understand if you can post a snapshot of it.

I suggest you back up the data from H & D drives & during installation split the merged drive (H & D). And install Ubuntu in one of them using GParted.

Comment: thanks, will try that. Also will try to post some screenshots.